# why are after a new react-native project lots of deprecation warnings?

Tags: ios, xcode, reactjs, react-native

steps to reproduce:

**installed versions:**

```
react 15.4.2
react-native 0.40.0
```

create a new Project

```
react-native init reactNativeTest
```

Running Project

```
1) Start Xcode
2) Open Project reactNativeTest
3) Run App
```

when I run it in xcode I get hellot of deprecation warnings, semantic issues and CoreFoundation Errors.

see screenshot

[image]

Comment: even in 0.52 I am seeing lots of warnings with XCode 9.1 around 148 warnings

Comment: 451 warnings in our project.

Answer (score 8):

These are known issues in React Native 0.40 ([reported in React Native github project as issue #11736](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11736)) that occur for others (myself as well) on a fresh project.

As of 17 minutes ago, there are a [number of pull requests](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11736#issuecomment-271468579) which reduce some of the issues.

One commenter on the issue reports that "Those are warning and you can mostly ignore those warning. You project should run fine with those warning."  I've confirmed this, but hopefully we'll get these warnings cleaned up soon.

Comment: Thanks a lot, so we'll wait for minor version upgrades. good to know

Comment: Do you suggest to 'apply all suggested changes' or is it better to fully trust RN and uncheck all of suggested modifications?

Comment: React Native is hot garbage if it can't build without any warnings. Warnings exist for a reason, having so many obscures important warnings in native code that we may actually need to fix. Scrolling through 450 warnings to find a compile error also sucks terribly.

Comment: @PeterW Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm actually a native developer working on a native framework integrated in a React application. Beyond the compile warnings, the huge number of console logging messages that also obscure valid problems, my difficulty of building only occasionally when react changes so often, etc, etc, our application also needs to work well in poor network connectivity environments. Given the problems I've had getting our app to work, let alone debugging it, in bad connectivity environments, I'm more inclined to recommend we switch to developing the UI in native Swift.

Answer (score 2):

**Why**

The OS Deployment target is way too low for many of these dependencies. Some are set to iphone 4!
I created a [bug](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29255) in React Native with this same solution

**Solution**

1. Copy function `min_OSTarget_post_install` into your Podfile
2. Call the function within post_install
3. pod install
4. See hundreds of Xcode warnings dissapear

**Code**

```
def min_OSTarget_post_install(installer)
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      if Gem::Version.new('8.0') > Gem::Version.new(config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'])
        config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '9.0'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

```
post_install do |installer|
  ...
  min_OSTarget_post_install(installer) // ADD THIS  LINE
end
```

Comment: Thanks! worked for me `React Native - 0.61.5` in 2022 Feb